# Implementing Python DB-API

Tags: python, python-db-api

I'm trying to implement the python DB-API for a small "database" that we built internally. This database does not expose an ODBC interface (or JDBC for that matter). My goal is to create a sqlalchemy for this so that I can use it with an application like Superset for example. I have created JDBC drivers in the past and that requires full Java implementation of the methods from the interfaces. In case of Python's DB-API, I couldn't find any example. Even the one I saw with psycopg2 https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2 is fully written in C and I'm not an expert on C.

Any way to implement the DB-API only in python? Is there any examples available? (Sorry if my understanding of db-api is not correct.)

Comment: Plenty of pure Python DB-API implementations out there if you don't stick to old databases ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can find plenty of DB-API drivers written in Python. The specific libraries depend on how your database communicates and packs/unpacks data.

- If you're database is listening on a port, you'll probably be using the [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html) module.
- If you're doing any kind of batch inserting or unpacking, you want to check out the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module as well.
- If you don't need support for Python 2, with Python 3.3+ you get [memoryview().cast()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memory-views), which may also come handy with regard to unpacking data.
- Python 3.8 comes with the [shared memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) module, which can help you out when you start optimizing.
- If your database runs on a specific platform, [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) comes handy for pulling out OS specific tweaks (Like manually implementing `shared memory` if you can't use Python 3.8).

Pandas used to support DB-API connections directly. It currently only supports the SQlite DB-API officially, but you can [piggyback it](https://github.com/EliYk/pysqream/blob/master/pysqream/dbapi.py#L992-L1000), which will allow you to [test yourself](https://github.com/EliYk/pysqream/blob/master/tests/dbapi_tests.py#L578-L623) with a known tool.

Comment: The pystream looks promising. I will check it out. Any other simple implementation? For now I just want to make a connection,  run a simple select query.